# bitbake recipe compiles but cannot be included into image

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have a recipe that compiles C code and I have a python recipe that depends on that C library. Both can be `bitbake`d and when I scrutinize the environment of the python recipe the C library shows up as expected. I also have an image recipe that adds the python recipe as `IMAGE_INSTALL`. When I check the dependency graph all dependencies seem to be resolved just fine. Nevertheless, compilation fails:

```
DNF version: 4.1.0
cachedir: /home/marius/mender-orangepi-warrior/build/tmp/work/orange_pi_zero-poky-linux-gnueabi/quakesaver-image/1.0-r0/rootfs/var/cache/dnf
Added oe-repo repo from /home/marius/mender-orangepi-warrior/build/tmp/work/orange_pi_zero-poky-linux-gnueabi/quakesaver-image/1.0-r0/oe-rootfs-repo
repo: using cache for: oe-repo
not found other for: 
not found modules for: 
not found deltainfo for: 
not found updateinfo for: 
oe-repo: using metadata from Fri 27 Mar 2020 11:40:54 AM UTC.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:01 ago on Fri 27 Mar 2020 11:40:54 AM UTC.
No module defaults found
No match for argument: wiringop
Error: Unable to find a match

ERROR: quakesaver-image-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: 
ERROR: quakesaver-image-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Function failed: do_rootfs
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/marius/mender-orangepi-warrior/build/tmp/work/orange_pi_zero-poky-linux-gnueabi/quakesaver-image/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_rootfs.20584
ERROR: Task (/home/marius/mender-orangepi-warrior/build/../sources/meta-quakesaver/recipes-core/images/quakesaver-image.bb:do_rootfs) failed with exit code '1'
```

Any hints, how to further investigate this issue? As I said, both dependencies are properly resolved in the graph. Strange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mistakenly had the C dependency added to the python runtime dependencies (`RDEPENDS_${PN}`) which, of course, is nonsense.